# Java regex to remove characters in a set but not between apexes

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use Java Regex, in order to remove characters in a set only if they are not within apexes. The characters between apexes is always just one.
This is an example of my inputs:

```
/src(;/unit/expr_stmt[3]/expr/operator[4]=')'\n
```

And this is the output I desire:

```
/src/unit/expr_stmt[3]/expr/operator[4]=')'\n
```

I have tried using negative lookahead but I wasn't able to achieve desired result.
This is the regex I composed:

```
[\\s;\\(\\),]+(?!('[^']+'))
```

I need to use Java Regex, because I have several different inputs.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: I'm maybe not the best at regex, but I think it might be better to split your String on apexes and use a regex on odd indexes of the resulting array.

Comment: Sorry, I meant even indexes. So that you keep the part within apexes away. Of course, that will break if you don't count escaped apexes as apexes.

Comment: Try `s=s.replaceAll("('[^']*')|[\\s;(),]+","$1");`

Comment: Can you show examples for semicolons that must remain? E.g. what about this? `asdf'gh;i'sadsd`. Should the regex remove the semicolon or not?

Comment: @JeremyGrand: Thanks but I prefer to solve the problem in a more general way with Regex.

Comment: @TamasRev: I have edited my question, the characters between apexes not to be removed, is always just one.

Comment: @delca85 ok, if it is juste one char between apexes, there's no need to split firsthand (I suggested that because trying to imagine what can be inside apexes can be tough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match and *capture* all substrings that start with a `'`, then have 0+ chars other than `'`, and have `'` right after. Then, match the chars you need to remove in all other contexts. As the replacement pattern, use the backreference to the captured value so as to restore it in the final result:

```
s=s.replaceAll("('[^']*')|[\\s;(),]+","$1");
```

**Details**:

- `('[^']*')` - capturing group 1 matching `'`, 0+ chars other than `'` and then `'`
- `|` - or
- `[\\s;(),]+` - 1+ whitespaces, `;`, `(`, `)` or `,`.

The `$1` in the replacement pattern refers to the value stored inside capturing group 1.

**NOTE**: if there can be escaped `'`, you would need to replace `'[^']*'` with `'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*'`.